# Peer getting rejected from the private network

Tags: scp, network

Hi I created a private network of 3 nodes with the following configurations like this:

```
# more than one node should validate. threashold = 2
[QUORUM_SET]
THRESHOLD_PERCENT=34
VALIDATORS=["$node01","$node02","$node03"]
```

so {node01, node02, node03} forms a quorum.

Now I want to connect another node - node04 with the following configuration :

```
[QUORUM_SET]
THRESHOLD_PERCENT=1
VALIDATORS=[
]
# threshold  = 3 (more than 2 nodes should validate)
[QUORUM_SET.1]
THRESHOLD_PERCENT=51
VALIDATORS=[
    "$node01", 
    "$node02", 
    "$node03",
    "$self"
]
```

But the node04 is getting reject and getting outofsync and hence not getting consensus. 
here is the error at node04 console :

```
successful handshake with GCOQO@127.0.0.1:11645
2019-06-13T14:26:15.972 GD6ED [Overlay INFO] successful handshake with GDOTQ@127.0.0.1:11625
2019-06-13T14:26:15.994 GD6ED [Overlay WARNING] Received error (ERR_LOAD): peer rejected
2019-06-13T14:26:15.994 GD6ED [Overlay INFO] Dropping peer GC2JH@127.0.0.1:11635
2019-06-13T14:26:15.994 GD6ED [Overlay WARNING] ignoring received localhost
2019-06-13T14:26:15.994 GD6ED [Overlay WARNING] ignoring received localhost
2019-06-13T14:26:15.994 GD6ED [Overlay WARNING] ignoring received localhost
2019-06-13T14:26:15.994 GD6ED [Overlay WARNING] ignoring received localhost
2019-06-13T14:26:15.995 GD6ED [Overlay ERROR] TCPPeer::drop shutdown socket failed: Transport endpoint is not connected [TCPPeer.cpp:195]
2019-06-13T14:26:15.995 GD6ED [Overlay WARNING] Received error (ERR_LOAD): peer rejected
```

Error at one of the other nodes :

```
New connected peer (empty)
2019-06-13T15:03:52.813 GCOQO [Overlay WARNING] New peer rejected, all slots taken
2019-06-13T15:03:52.813 GCOQO [Overlay INFO] Dropping peer GD6ED@127.0.0.1:11655
```

Here I have 2 questions:

- Q1) Am I doing some incorrect configuration ?
- Q2) When I am adding node04, then, in that case, the quourum is still {node01, node02, node03} right?
- Q3) Is there any proper documentation of connecting a new node with main network ?

TIA!

Edit:

I stopped all of the nodes and added node04 in the list of preferred peers and restarted everything again and it worked.

Now the question is, In case I want to become a validator node in main network , then do I have to publish my IP to the community so that they can add me in their preferred peers?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to publish your IP. Once you're connected to the network your address will be somehow announced and you'll get incoming connections pretty soon.

Answer (score 0):

I understood what I was doing wrong. I had set `PREFERRED_PEERS_ONLY=true` which is why it rejected other incoming peers. After setting it to `false` the network working fine.

So if you get stuck with this kind of situation check the following thing in your network configurations:

1. Check for `TARGET_PEER_CONNECTIONS`
2. Check for `MAX_ADDITIONAL_PEER_CONNECTIONS`
3. Check for `PREFERRED_PEERS_ONLY`

Description of these are present [here](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/stellar-core_example.cfg)